# Installing Pillow: "Unable to locate package libwebpmux3"

Tags: python-imaging-library, raspberry-pi-zero

I am trying to install Pillow on a Raspberry Pi Zero W.  I am going through these instructions:

https://brachiograph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get-started/install.html

When I run:

```
sudo apt install libwebp6 libtiff5 libjbig0 liblcms2-2 libwebpmux3 libopenjp2-7 libzstd1 libwebpdemux2
```

I get the error:

> E: Unable to locate package libwebpmux3

Any ideas on how to resolve this?  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to setup a `BrachioGraph` (https://brachiograph.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get-started/install.html) on Raspberry Pi (Raspbian).
I updated to the latest Raspbian version via the Raspberry Pi website, and was able to install this library.